# Cannot read property of undefined error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use an array to get a specific result but i get the error **cannot read property of undefined** but when i console log that same property i get my result here is my code :

```
for (var j=0;j<$scope.ftListe.length;j++){
    if(task[j].projet_id==id){
        if(temp!=task[j].NomTache)
            temptache.push(task[j]);
        tempcol.push(lecollaborateur[j]);
    }
    temp=task[j].NomTache;
}
$scope.temptache=temptache;
$scope.tempcol=tempcol;

for(var i=0; i<temptache.length;i++){
    for (var k=0;k<$scope.ftListe.length;i++){
        console.log("l'id de la tache: "+temptache[i].IdTache);
        if(temptache[i].IdTache==$scope.ftListe[k].tacheid){
            temps = temps+$scope.ftListe[k].TempsPasse;
            passe= passe+$scope.ftListe[k].TempsPasse * lecollaborateur[k].CoutParJour;
        }
    }
    tempsAr.push(temps);
    passeAr.push(passe);
    temps=0; passe=0;
}
```

The property I get the error from is `IdTache`, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: console temptache and check if it has IdTache?

Comment: @Dinesh when i console temptache[i].IdTache I get the result with no problems

Comment: If you really want the help, you should provide us with a Plunkr or JSFiddle so we could debug since we can't help like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the following lines:

```
for(var i=0; i<temptache.length;i++){
    for (var k=0;k<$scope.ftListe.length;i++){
```

Note that in the inner `for` loop, you increment the `i` variable (`i++`) instead of `k`. So this make `i` to get increment in the inner loop to an out of bounds offset.

The JS runtime error prevent your script from going into an Infinite loop - So when you stated that *"when i console log that same property i get my result"* it actually show the results up until the point where you're in the valid range of the `temptache` array.

You should fix it to:

```
for(var i=0; i<temptache.length;i++){
    for (var k=0;k<$scope.ftListe.length;k++){
```

Comment: Mondays can be rough ... ;-)

Comment: @AlonEitan , i completely missed that, thank you all